# In AppleScript and BBEdit how can you check links?

Tags: html, file, applescript, bbedit

In BBEdit there is the command under `Markup -> Check -> Document Links` shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> that checks all links.  When I look at the dictionary under `BBEdit > HTML Scripting -> check links` it shows:

[image]

but when I try to script against a project with:

```
set theResult to check links of active document of project window 1
```

I get an Error of `item`, when I try to check based on the filename with:

```
set foobar to (name of active document of project window 1) as string
set theResult to check links of foobar
```

I still get the same error, if I try:

```
set projectPath to file of project document 1
set theResult to check links of projectPath
```

I get a returned of `{}`.  Thinking it was an issue with not adding `with show results` I changed it to:

```
set theResult to check links of projectPath with show results
```

but I get a return of `activate`

When I search through Google I'm unable to find a solution on if it's possible to return a boolean on wether the links in the HTML file are valid when scripting through the content.  So my question is, how can I get AppleScript to tell me the links are valid in BBEdit with `check links`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the links from the file of the active document:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    set theFilePathOfFrontProject to file of text document 1 -- get the path of the selected file in the front project window
    set theResult to (check links of theFilePathOfFrontProject) is {}
    if theResult  then
        display dialog "All links appear to be valid"
    else
        display dialog "Some links appear to be not valid"
    end if
end tell
```

---

Informations :

`set projectPath to file of project document 1`, this command return the path of the project (check links on this file will always return an empty list), the path will be `file "fullpath:someName.bbprojectd"`, it's not the path of the selected **HTML** file in the project.

To get path of all files of the project : `set allFilePaths to project collections of project document 1 --   list of paths`

Comment: Ya I ended up using something similar but it took more lines but in the end it was a conditional checking if the list was empty but plus 1 for the solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe this worked last time I used it, I'm on mobile about to board a flight so syntax may have gotten mumbled.

```
set theFile to ((path to documents folder) as string) & "test.html"
set theResult to check links of file theFile
```

To use system events to press keys, you could use a separate tell block, or create a handler like so.

```
on checkLinks()
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "k" using {command down, control down}
    end tell
end checkLinks
```

then call the handler as usual

```
my checkLinks()
```